# SVN - Working Copy version/format issues

Tags: python, svn

I have an issue with trying to find a balance between my SVN version and my working copy. Initially I got a message telling me to upgrade the working copy, which I did. Now I am being told to downgrade the working copy (not as simple as upgrading), or upgrade your SVN version, not possible.

I discovered a python script which comes to the rescue, it's change-svn-wc-format.py. it's recommended you run as folows....

`python change-svn-wc-format.py WC-PATH svn version`

I'm now getting this error:

```
 ERROR: Unsupported version number '1.7.5'; only 1.4, 1.5, and 1.6 can
 be supported
```

So I changed to version 1.6 and now I'm getting:

```
Unrecognized WC format 12 in WC PATH only formats 8, 9, and 10 can be supported
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should update your svn client to 1.7.5. Yet another way is to remove local copy and checkout it from the server.

This link may be helpfull too: [How can I downgrade the version of an SVN working copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716021/how-can-i-downgrade-the-version-of-an-svn-working-copy)

Comment: As I understand, your WC is already in 12 format, so you do not need to run upgrade script. Do you have any troubles when using svn client?

Comment: I've no problem with SVN client. I think I need to change the foramt of the WC

Comment: Well, if the client doesn't have problems with the working copy why  upgrade? If you get 'upgrade working copy' message when run the svn client, try to run 'svn upgrade'. It may help.

Comment: I'm confused sorry, I have to go back over the situation. What I do know is when I try and run a script that uses svn, it asks me to downgrade the WC

Comment: Both error messages in the question are from the change-svn-wc-format.py script. You do not need to run it because the WC is already in the format compatible with your svn client.

Comment: That's my thinking too....... here's the error mesage i get when I run the file to check out to svn ..... This client is too old to work with working copy......  You need to get a newer Subversion client, or to downgrade this working copy.

Comment: Run 'svn --version' to make sure that you run the right client. If it is not the case, try to checkout fresh WC from the server to the new empty folder.